# How to return to `ipdb` prompt from `IPython` prompt

Tags: python, ipdb

I've recently started using `ipdb` for debugging. Colours are nicer than with the default debugger.

But I keep finding myself in an IPython prompt, and whenever I exit the IPython prompt I exit the whole program. How do I return from the IPython prompt to ipdb?

Example below:

```
ipdb > c
In :
```

At this point:

```
In : exit
<IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall object at 0x7fb204e67700>
In :
```

or

```
In : exit()
In :
```

or CTRL-D quits the whole program

Magic commands also not great:

```
In : %quit
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    %quit
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If you suspect this is an IPython 8.10.0 bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True

In : %exit
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    %exit
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If you suspect this is an IPython 8.10.0 bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True
```

How can I get back to my ipdb prompt?

Comment: You tried %exit or %quit ?

Comment: thanks for asking @6c00h - updated the question with results of doing those

Comment: Ah try exit or quit without %

Comment: Those indicate that they are functions:

In : exit
<IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall object at 0x7fb204e67700>

But don't get anywhere beyond that. 

I've also tried downgrading IPython to a 7.x version but that hasn't helped either

Comment: use the debug magic command without any arguments %debug